# Touch-screen users have to click link twice for it to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

I have this drop-down menu that drops down on hover normally, but on touch devices, I simply made it so that you can click to open it as well.

The problem is that it seems like the `<ul>` that drops down isn't completely in focus or something because I have to click the links twice on my iPhone 4 to make them work.

Here's the code I'm working with:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.myMenu > li').bind('mouseover', openSubMenu);
    $('.myMenu > li').bind('mouseout', closeSubMenu);
    $('.myMenu > li').bind('click', toggleSubMenu);

    /* Also tried, currently using:
    $('.myMenu > li').bind('tap', toggleSubMenu);
    */

    function openSubMenu() {
        $(this).find('ul').addClass("hovered");
    };

    function closeSubMenu() {
        $(this).find('ul').removeClass("hovered");
    };

    function toggleSubMenu() {
        $(this).find('ul').toggleClass("hovered").focus();
    };

});
```

The `.focus()` was the fix I tried adding. It didn't break the code but didn't fix it either. I know there are several things I can do to make it better for touch-devices, but for now, the click method is what I'm sticking with.

By the way:

```
.hovered{
    opacity:1 !important;
    visibility: visible !important;
}
```

The HTML setup is basically `<ul>`s inside `<ul>`s like you would expect from a drop-down menu. If you for some reason want the markup just say so and I'll add it.

EDIT: Here's the link to the website I'm working on:
http://bok-it.underbakke.net

EDIT: Some additional information you might find useful that I noticed just now. The first time I click the link, the CSS on that link acts like it's hovered (as : hover) when I click on the sub-link the first time the main link (the one I first clicked to show the dropdown) loses the state of hover. This is why I think this is a focus issue.

EDIT: The HTML markup as requested:

```
<ul class="myMenu">
        <li><a href="/"><span class="icon-home"></span> Framside</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="nbutikk"><span class="icon-cart"></span> Butikk</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/sand"><span class="icon-cart"></span> Sand</a></li>
                <li><a href="/sauda"><span class="icon-cart"></span> Sauda</a></li>
               <li><a href="http://kontorhandel.no"><span class="icon-cart"></span> Nettbutikk</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#" id="nit-tjenester"><span class="icon-console"></span> IT Tjenester</a>
           <ul>
                <li><a href="/driftsavtale"><span class="icon-console"></span> Driftsavtale</a></li>
                <li><a href="/asp_vps"><span class="icon-console"></span> ASP & VPS</a></li>
                <li><a href="/overvaking"><span class="icon-console"></span> Overvåking</a></li>
                <li><a href="/nettverk"><span class="icon-console"></span> Nettverk</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#" id="nsupport"><span class="icon-info"></span> Support</a>
           <ul>
                <li><a href="/fjernsupport"><span class="icon-info"></span> Fjernsupport</a></li>
                <li><a href="/utskrift_asp"><span class="icon-info"></span> Utskrift ASP</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="/rdp_rycloud"><span class="icon-info"></span> RDP: Rycloud</a></li>
                <li><a href="teamviewer_host"><span class="icon-info"></span> TeamViewer Host</a></li>
                                </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="/kontakt"><span class="icon-mail"></span> Kontakt Oss</a></li>
    </ul>
```

--------------SOLUTION--------------

EDIT: For people that are seeking the solution to this, here's the jQuery that fixed it for me (You should also give @jonsuh an upvote for wipping out the solution):

```
$(".myMenu li ul li a").on("touchend", function(event) {
  window.location.href = $(this).attr("href");
});
```

Comment: can you plz put the html markup as well

Comment: @V31 Sure, I've added it now :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

When you mouseover a link in the submenu, the state of the parent list item changes.

However in iOS, when you click on a link in the submenu, it detects that the parent list item state needs to change, so instead of executing a tap, it's changing the state of the item, which is why it's requiring a second tap. (I hope this makes sense).

To cut to the chase, make sure there isn't a state change in the parent list item. Keep it the same when you hover over it as when you're hovering over the submenu links.

I haven't tested these and it's tough when I'm not working with the code live, but possible solutions could be as follows:

You could do it with jQuery and detecting a touch end, which isn't the best solution, but it *should* work:

```
$(".myMenu ul li a").on("touchend", function(event) {
  window.location.href = $(this).attr("href");
});
```

Another is to try to keep the state the same with CSS and it may keep Safari from detecting a change in state. (I removed my CSS answer since it didn't work)

Comment: Okay I *think* I get it. How would I go about fixing this, if you have  any quick recommendations?

Comment: I love your answer. Very descriptive, I learnt a lot and it helped me feel less dumb. Honestly if I could give you 10 upvotes I would. I just want to note for anyone that might have this problem, the CSS didn't work for some reason, but the jQuery did when I changed the selector to ".myMenu li ul li a"

Comment: Why in all of the goodness in the world would they implement this? Jeeze lets just go back to using flash if they're going to do arbitrary decision making like this for us. It completely breaks a lot of standard industry practice models that, apparently, you have to "fix" with JAVASCRIPT. What the heck??

Comment: I wouldn't advise solving these problems with JS like that. The root for solving those issues is to know the CSS quirks of iOS in this regard. For more context on this, please refer to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34701035/1647538) on a similar issue .

Answer (score 7):

Read this: http://sitr.us/2011/07/28/how-mobile-safari-emulates-mouse-events.html

> But if a clickable element also does something on mouseover then tapping on that element will trigger a mouseover event instead of a click. Tapping on the same element again will produce a click event.

If you have a mouseover event, iOS (maybe other OSes) will fire that upon initial click rather than the actual click event. I'd add some alerts to your JS to see which event, exactly, is being called on that initial tap.

Comment: I see. I'll do that. In case, do you recommend I maybe have the mouseover and mouseout events only on desktops? How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of having the click event of Jquery try the tap event like

```
$('.myMenu > li').bind('tap', toggleSubMenu);
```

[Documentation for Tap](http://api.jquerymobile.com/tap/)

Comment: I still have to tap twice to go to the link for some reason. I'll add a link to the question to the page I'm working on too.

Comment: I believe there is also a 'touch' or 'touchstart' as well as the tap, maybe one of these would work.

Comment: isn't the tap event only for jquery mobile?

Comment: you might also try to bind to the 'vclick' event which is supposed to "do the right thing" in any client.

Answer (score 2):

I forget where I found this solution but with jQuery I do something like this and it seems to do the trick:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a,input').bind('touchend', function() {});
});
```

I used to use 'touchstart' but 'touchend' seems to be working better.