# Double Tap Bug on IE Touch in IE10-IE11 (links must be tapped twice)

Tags: hover, touch, internet-explorer-11, wai-aria, ie-mobile

I was faced with this problem on IE11 Mobile (Lumia 520 Phone) on an existing navigation menu, where every link inside my submenus were not firing a click, on the first tap.

This [fiddle repro](https://fiddle.jshell.net/hexalys/vtczc7s3/show/light/) is a partial flyout accessible navigation menu, taken from a sample [WAI app menu](http://www.w3.org/WAI/tutorials/menus/examples/appmenu/).

If you test it on IE10 or IE11 Mobile or Touch, you will obverse that none of the submenu links work.

They must be clicked twice to fire the click events.

Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bug is a result of a feature to ["help simulate hover on touch-enabled devices"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj152135(v=vs.85).aspx) that was deployed starting in IE10-11 for Touch.

In short, what causes and requires the double tap is having `aria-haspopup=true` as the submenu parent element level. Because of it, IE Touch wrongly assumes all those links are toggle themselves and treat them as such. I shall also note that for similar reasons, iOS Safari has its own way to treat [elements with “*:hover[s] that either hides or shows another element using visibility or display*”](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34701035/1647538).

As explained on MSDN’s [Internet Explorer 10 Samples and Tutorials](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj152141(v=vs.85).aspx):

> Alternatively, Internet Explorer 10 adds new behavior to the existing aria-haspopup property to simulate hover on page elements with hidden interactive content.

The issue is that while it was supposedly designed to be helpful, that implementation is based on an incomplete and somewhat misguided reading of what [aria-haspopup](http://www.w3.org/WAI/tutorials/menus/flyout/#improve-screen-reader-support-using-wai-aria) is, and what it is supposed to do.

1. [`aria-haspopup`](http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/states_and_properties#aria-haspopup) is technically a property (and not state). Meaning that IE placed a touch behavior on an element that isn’t supposed to change at runtime. Unless a responsive context would perhaps require such a change; `aria-haspopup='true'` shall remain `true` even if the popup element is shown. The state for the switch being [`aria-expanded`](http://www.w3.org/WAI/tutorials/menus/flyout/#improve-screen-reader-support-using-wai-aria) instead.
2. The concept only works for the [MSDN example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj152141(v=vs.85).aspx) of aria-haspopup  as implemented on that tutorial. i.e. **If** `aria-haspopup=true` is placed on the toggle button itself, that IE Touch feature will work as intended. **However** if the `aria-haspopup=true` attributes  is placed at the parent level like my repro, or like a more traditional app menu, as per this [W3C/WAI example](http://www.w3.org/WAI/tutorials/menus/examples/appmenu/), it's a problem.

The solutions to go around this bug are to, either not use `aria-haspopup=true` on parent elements because of IE10-11 Touch (which sucks for accessibility), or remove it from touch enabled IE10/IE11, either on the server side or with Javascript accordingly.

Comment: Although it seems to be a further misuse of aria-haspopup and cumbersome for large submenus, you can work around this by giving child elements aria-haspopup="false"